# How to call object of the native-lib in java

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, java-native-interface

I am making an Document Scanner. I'm using opencv for image processing. In camera view i'm bounding rectangle on largest contour. It is detecting largest contour properly. And now i want to capture only boudingRect which is written in native-lib.cpp. So i want object of native-lib in java class. help to get that.

**Native-lib.cpp**

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_prisca_ctest_OpenCvCamera_doWithMat(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong matAddrGr,
                                     jlong matAddrRgba) {
try {
    Mat &image = *(Mat *) matAddrRgba;
    Rect bounding_rect;

    Mat thr(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(image, thr, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Convert to gray
    threshold(thr, thr, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU); //Threshold the gray

    vector<vector<Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(thr, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP,
                 CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); // Find the contours in the image
    sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(),
         compareContourAreas);            //Store the index of largest contour
    bounding_rect = boundingRect((const _InputArray &) contours[0]);

rectangle(image, bounding_rect, Scalar(250, 250, 250) , 5);
} catch (int a) {

}
}
```

**Activity**

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cam);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
            File imgFolder = new File(FILE_LOCATION);
            imgFolder.mkdir();
            File image = new File(imgFolder, "Scan" + timestamp + ".jpg");
            String fileName = FILE_LOCATION +
                    "/Scan" + timestamp + ".jpg";
            Toast.makeText(OpenCvCamera.this, image + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(fileName, mRgba);
        }
    }) ;
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // input frame has RGBA format
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    mGray = inputFrame.gray();
    doWithMat(mGray.getNativeObjAddr(), mRgba.getNativeObjAddr());
    return mRgba;

}
```

What should i add above Imgcodecs.imwrite(fileName, mRgba) to crop the matrix and save only boundingRect part?

Comment: Note that you should replace the `c++` tag with `jni`, because one of your snippet includes `jni` code (which is `c++`, anyway)

Comment: After a second reading, it seems more like a pure `opencv` issue. You're basically only asking what method to use to crop a matrix/image using `opencv`, right?

Comment: Not totally, bcoz i m getting boudingRect on cameraview. So when i click on capture button it should capture only bounding Rect. @Nepho

Comment: Currently i can capture image but it captures whole surface. @Nepho

Comment: As I said, it seems that you're looking for an easy answer to "how do I crop a boudingRect in OpenCV" without reading through the documentation first. If you don't want to read the documentation for it, I suggest you try to look it up online, or post a more relevant question

Comment: Actually i know how to crop but i m confuse bcoz my bounding rect function is in native. so how to call that?                                                                  
 Mat cropped = mRgba.submat( bounding_rect );
                Imgcodecs.imwrite(fileName, cropped);          just like this right? @Nepho

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you want to call the native JNI method `Java_prisca_ctest_OpenCvCamera_doWithMat`.

First, to call this method from the Java side, you need to declare it. To declare it, you need to understand the name of the method, which gives you everything you need:

1. **Java**_prisca_ctest_OpenCvCamera_doWithMat: This means that this is to be executed by Java.
2. Java_**prisca_ctest**_OpenCvCamera_doWithMat: This part is the package of the class.
3. Java_prisca_ctest_**OpenCvCamera**_doWithMat: This part is the name of the Java class.
4. Java_prisca_ctest_OpenCvCamera_**doWithMat**: This part is the name of the method.

With that in mind, we need to know the parameters. In this case it's easy: the two `jlong` arguments translate to a Java `long`.

Create a `OpenCvCamera.java` class, and put this in it:

```
package prisca.ctest; // This part might actually be ctest.prisca, not sure

public class OpenCvCamera {
    public static native void doWithMat(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);
}
```

You can now call the method by importing the class and calling `OpenCvCamera.doWithMat(long, long)`. Note that this might not be 100% correct, I'm not that good with JNI (especially writing about it off the top of my head), but this should get you started :)

Comment: i know that and already call JNI method, thats why i m getting Rectangle in camera view, i m stucked at capturing rectangle area.

Comment: I tried to understand your issue, but your question honestly doesn't make sense. Why include that specific part of your JNI? Hell, why even include the java below? To me it seems that you're just looking for the correct opencv function to achieve what you want to achieve. You said in a comment that you had trouble calling a native method, and I just gave you a walkthrough of how to do that. If that's not what you wanted... I can't help you any further

Comment: I have trouble in calling native object